# org-preview-latex rendering weirdness when a space after initial inline expression delimiter

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

`\(S\)` renders fine. No problem here.

`$S$` renders fine. No problem here.

`$ S $` does nothing. I wouldn't expect this. Comment below referencing manual explains this case.

`$S $` does nothing. I wouldn't expect this. Comment below referencing manual explains this case.

`\( S \)` renders with an image of TLT TLT over the expression. Using luatex. Weird. This remains unexplained.

`\(S \)` renders fine. Similar to previous but notice no space after initial inline expression delimiter.

I wouldn't expect spaces just after the opening inline expression delimiter to be a problem.

Question: Any ideas on what I should look at in my config to allow space after opening inline delimiter `\(`?

This issue happens when rendering org-mode latex fragments. I have found that it happens with the default value of `org-preview-latex-process-alist` of:

```
((dvipng :programs
         ("latex" "dvipng")
         :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
         (1.0 . 1.0)
         :latex-compiler
         ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
         :image-converter
         ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
          ("latex" "dvisvgm")
          :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
          (1.7 . 1.5)
          :latex-compiler
          ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
              ("latex" "convert")
              :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
              (1.0 . 1.0)
              :latex-compiler
              ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
              :image-converter
              ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

and default value for `org-preview-latex-default-process` of: dvipng.

Update: This happens when Org version > 9.0 uses its default config, i.e., no use of luatex. I am no longer using luatex but the problem still remains.

Comment: You mean that you are now not using LuaTeX but you still get that `TLT TLT`  junk in the '\(...\)` case? Have you cleaned out all the files that LuaTeX produced? Also, have you cleaned out the `ltximg/' subidr? There may be old stuff there, confusing the issue.

Comment: That did solve it for the case I presented above. I am still trying to figure out why a particular file doesn't render as mentioned in my comments below. You have answered it and I will award that, but want to keep it open for a bit longer in case you or someone else has an insight on why that particular files inline math expressions don't render correctly for me with default org-preview-latex-process-alist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $-delimited cases, there is a simple explanation: you are not allowed to have a space after the opening delimiter and before the closing delimiter. The [manual](https://orgmode.org/org.html#LaTeX-fragments) says:

> Text within the usual LaTeX math delimiters.  To avoid conflicts
> with currency specifications, single ‘$’ characters are only
> recognized as math delimiters if the enclosed text contains at most
> two line breaks, is directly attached to the ‘$’ characters with no
> whitespace in between, and if the closing ‘$’ is followed by
> whitespace, punctuation or a dash.  For the other delimiters, there
> is no such restriction, so when in doubt, use `\(...\)` as inline
> math delimiters.

Using default settings for the `dvipng` section of `org-preview-latex-process-alist` and the `dvipng` setting for `org-preview-latex-default-process`, all the `\(...\)` constructs work, both when exporting to PDF and when previewing.

One possibility is that you have old files produced by LuaTeX, polluting your environment, in particular, the PNG files in the `ltximg/` subdirectory. When you remove those, the preview mechanism will be forced to recreate them with the current settings.

Comment: Thanks for looking that up in the manual @NickD. I've updated the question. No longer using luatex at all and it still remains. You have explained the dollar delimiter cases though, thanks. Now I need to figure out why for the `\(\)` delimiters. Are you able to render `\( S \)` or `\(S \)` successfully? At least that would  show me that the issue is in my config possibly.

Comment: All the `\(...\)` delimited cases work for me, both when I export to PDF and also when I preview latex fragments. Can you reproduce your finding starting with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. They work fine for me with emacs -Q as well. Will be interesting to see what in my config is responsible.

Comment: As I mentioned, it might be something in your environment, rather than in your config.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Comment: Ok, after deleting lxtimg dir the examples I provided work fine. However,I get a different output when using Org's default preview latex process config on the following file (which I believe must use luatex or xetex for unicode math chars): https://github.com/Anton-Latukha/haskell-notes/blob/master/README.org, i.e., dvipng: org-compile-file: File "/var/folders/b_/wfcn1_mx71bcj3rmvn0_rt2r0000gn/T/orgtexj8hoHn.dvi" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘dvipng’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.

Comment: Rendering that file at the link above was actually the impetus for me to switch to luatex in the first place from Org's default which we see renders `\( S \)` fine. I don't normally use unicode in latex fragments, but perhaps that file is just actually showing prettify symbols which I don't normally use. I'd like to have my config handle unicode math chars fine though, so maybe I should try a xetex config for org-mode instead of luatex to handle such a file. I may be off-base though on the real problem with rendering that file.

Comment: Just a follow up that this was resolved here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/can-you-render-the-latex-math-expressions-in-the-following-file-successfully-ht.   If anyone is curious what it was.